# How to get a camera preview's pixels in Android?

Tags: java, android, camera, preview, pixel

I want to know how to get an array of pixels from the preview webcam (which I will run in a service). I've heard that the preview has to be displayed on a surface, but there will be no surface if I use a service.

I am very new to Android development, sorry for any misconceptions.

Thanks.

Comment: [This Google Search](https://www.google.com/#q=get%20camera%20preview%20pixels%20android) yielded [Android: Retrieving the Camera preview as a Pixel Array](http://www.41post.com/3470/programming/android-retrieving-the-camera-preview-as-a-pixel-array) as the first search result.

Comment: is it an external WebCam (USB or WiFi or BT), or the internal camera *used as* a WebCam?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
       Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

       if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
       {
           parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);                           
           camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
       }
      camera.setParameters(parameters);


      camera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraSurfaceHolder);
      camera.startPreview();
      previewing = true;
```